# Update the same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to update the same table data from same table data.

My SP is as shown below :

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Name = T2.Name
   , T1.Age = T2.Age
   , T1.Subject = T2.Subject
FROM Student T1
   , Student T2
WHERE T1.StudentID = @OldID
   AND T2.StudentID = @NewID
```

When I am executing this query, there is no error. But the update is not working.

[here NO Common column values to compare like T1.StudentID = T2.StudentID]

Comment: Are `@OldID` and `@NewID` identical?

Comment: Your query ought to work (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7728/13). Perhaps `@OldID` and `@NewID` are identical as @Oded suggests.

Comment: Yes they are identical. Studentid is uniqueidentifier.

Comment: @SunilShah I think when they asked if `@OldID` and `@NewID` are identical, they meant the _value_ and not the _data type_. If the _values_ are the same, then yes, your query will appear not to work because nothing needed to be updated.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.name = t2.name, t1.age = t2.age, t1.subject = t2.subject
FROM student t1
INNER JOIN
student t2
ON t1.StudentID = @oldID
AND t2.StudentID = @NewID
```

The full example is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42bee/5)

Comment: Can this be used to update multiple rows from one source row?

Comment: I posted a followup question, it'd be great if you would take a look.  Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949195/copy-data-to-existing-rows-within-same-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Try this one , you are using wrong alias .

```
UPDATE T1 SET Name = T2.Name
, Age = T2.Age
, Subject = T2.Subject
 FROM Student T1
, Student T2
WHERE T1.StudentID = @OldID
AND T2.StudentID = @NewID
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do it through a stored procedure, declare some variables, load the new values to these variables, then update your table.

Should look something like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure2

    @OldID int,
    @NewID int

AS

declare @Name text, @Age int, @Subject text

begin

select @Name = T1.Name, @Age = T1.Age, @Subject= T1.Subject
from Student T1
Where T1.StudentID = @OldID

end

begin

UPDATE T1 SET T1.Name = @Name, T1.Age = @Age, T1.Subject = @Subject
FROM Student T1
WHERE T1.StudentID = @OldID

end
    RETURN
```