# Copy Data To Existing Rows Within Same Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

In SQL Server 2008, I want to update some of the rows with data from another row.  For example, given the sample data below:

```
ID   |     NAME           |    PRICE
---------------------------------------
 1   | Yellow Widget      |  2.99
 2   | Red Widget         |  4.99
 3   | Green Widget       |  4.99
 4   | Blue Widget        |  6.99
 5   | Purple Widget      |  1.99
 6   | Orange Widget      |  5.99
```

I want to update rows with ID 2, 3, and 5 to have the price of row 4.

I found a nice solution to update a single row at [Update the same table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842251/update-the-same-table-in-sql-server#answer-12842345) that basically looks like:

```
DECLARE  @src int = 4
        ,@dst int = 2  -- but what about 3 and 5 ?

UPDATE  DST
SET     DST.price = SRC.price
FROM    widgets DST
    JOIN widgets SRC ON SRC.ID = @src AND DST.ID = @dst;
```

But since I'm need to update multiple rows I'm not sure how the `JOIN` should look like.  `SRC.ID = @src AND DST.ID IN (2, 3, 5)` ? (not sure if that's even valid SQL?)

Also, if anyone can explain how the solution above does not update all the rows in the table since there is no `WHERE` clause, that would be great!

Any thoughts?  TIA!

Comment: Is it a one time activity that you have to perform or there is some logic behind the updates..

Comment: It's not necessarily a one time thing, but definitely not a frequently recurring thing either.  For the sake of answering your question it can be considered a one-time data maintenance action that needs to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use table variables to store the `ID`s to be updated:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (2), (3), (5);

DECLARE @destID INT = 4

UPDATE widgets 
    SET price = (SELECT price FROM widgets WHERE ID = @destID)
WHERE
    ID IN(SELECT ID FROM @tbl)
```

Alternatively, you can store the source ID and destination ID in a single table variable. For this case, you need to store `(2, 4)`, `(3, 4)` and `(5, 4)`.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(srcID INT, destID INT, PRIMARY KEY(srcID, destID));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (2, 4), (3, 4), (5, 4);

UPDATE s
    SET s.Price = d.Price
FROM widgets s
INNER JOIN @tbl t ON t.srcID = s.ID
INNER JOIN widgets d
    ON d.ID = t.destID
```